# Is it possible to send a request to the server when onDestroy is invoked

Tags: android

I want to empty the table on the server side for a mac address when the user closes the application. Therefore, I am trying to call the `emptyTable()` in the `ClearTable` class. Currently when I close the app the `emptyTable()` is being invoked but the nothing happen in the 'donInBackground()'?

**MainActivity class**

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();      
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress();

     JsonObject  jsonObject = new  JsonObject();
     jsonObject.addProperty("mac", macAddress);

    String json = jsonObject.toString();

    ClearTable ct = new ClearTable();
    ct.emptyTable(json);
}
```

**ClearTable class:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.json.JSONStore;

public class ClearTable {

    public void emptyTable(String json){
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(json);

    }

    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> {
        ArrayList<Integer> routes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Integer> doInBackground(String... params) {
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                System.out.println("The output of : doInBackground "
                        + params[0]);
                URL myUrl = new URL(
                        "https://serverside-apple.rhcloud.com/webapi/test");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl
                        .openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.connect();             
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                        conn.getOutputStream());
                // write to the output stream from the string
                wr.writeBytes(params[0]);
                wr.close();             
                System.out.println("xyz The output of getResponsecode: "
                 + conn.getResponseCode());

            } catch (IOException e) {    
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                        return null;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Integer> result) {

        }

    }

}
```

**Edit Code with the IntentService:**

onDestroy in the MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress();

     JsonObject  jsonObject = new  JsonObject();
     jsonObject.addProperty("mac", macAddress);

    System.out.println("JsonObject" + jsonObject);

    String json = jsonObject.toString();

    Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
            ClearTable.class);
    intent2.putExtra("json_mac", json);
    startService(intent2);
```

}

IntentService class:

```
public class ClearTable extends IntentService{

    public ClearTable() {
        super("IntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            String jSONString = intent.getStringExtra("json_mac");
            System.out.println("xyz The output of : doInBackground "
                    + jSONString);
            URL myUrl = new URL(
                    "https://serverside-apple.rhcloud.com/webapi/test");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.connect();             
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                    conn.getOutputStream());
            // write to the output stream from the string
            wr.writeBytes(jSONString);
            wr.close();             
            System.out.println("xyz The output of getResponsecode: "
             + conn.getResponseCode());

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }   

    }

}
```

Manifest:

```
 <service android:name=".ClearTable" />
```

Comment: From Android documntaion regarding onDestroy:

"Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data! For example, if an activity is editing data in a content provider, those edits should be committed in either onPause() or onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), not here."

Answer (score 0):

you can use background service at this place. call that service in onDestroy(). 
while this process will over service will close.

ex.

1. http://javatechig.com/android/creating-a-background-service-in-android
2. https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: Can I use `IntentService`?

Comment: Please see my edit code. I have tried it with IntentService but after starting the service in `onDestroy()` the `ClearTable` service is not being invoked!?

Answer (score 0):

Using background service when onDestroy method invoking is a good choice, but if you exit your app with android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()), onDestroy will probably not invoke.

Comment: I am not using `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())` maybe Android because when I put the code onStrop() it works.